# lower function in python shell not working when printing output

Tags: python

I am running this syntax which i have written under, but i get an error in the shell saying Attributeerror 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

```
>>> test = "HELLO"
>>> print (test).lower()
```

Comment: What do you think you're calling `lower` on? (It's not `test`.)

Comment: I think you meant to write `print(test.lower())`

Comment: That works in python2 but not python3. What @pault wrote works in python3

Comment: To further clarify, what I wrote works in both `python2` and `python3`. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are doing something wrong because:

```
>>> 'HELLO'.lower()
    'hello'
```

and

```
>>> test = 'HELLO'
>>> print (test).lower()
hello
>>> print test.lower()
hello
```

both works fine in python2.7

In python 3.6 (at least):

```
>>> print (test.lower())
hello
>>> print ((test).lower())
hello
```

But you are trying to execute lower method of result of print that is None.

```
>>> print(type(print('hi')))
hi
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run what you posted again in your shell and look at what happens.  Here's what happens in mine: (Windows 7-64, Python 3.6.3, both 32 and 64 bit):

```
>>> test = "HELLO"
>>> print(test).lower()
    HELLO
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    print(test).lower()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

You can see that the print(test) is running, and displaying "HELLO". The print function always returns NoneType, so the next step for the interpreter is trying to run NoneType.lower(), which throws an error.

Another way to do it is this:

```
>>>test = "HELLO"
>>>small = test.lower()
>>>print(small)
   hello
```

or

```
>>>print(test.lower())
```